# CKEDITOR at FireFox take a time to be loaded round 7 seconds i want to reduce this time

Tags: ckeditor

I am using Ckeditor. It Works fine on chrome but its taking too much time to load on  Fire Fox take a time to be loaded  round 7 seconds i want to reduce that  time to be open quickly

Comment: Any progress? Did you solve this or ignore it or use something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to profile your page. Meaning that you need to collect data on what specifically is taking so long to load and trying to improve those areas. [Here is a nice Firefox profiling link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Profiler). Here's a small checklist off the top of my dome that might help - always when doing changes, measure the impact they have on loading times using some kind of tool.

1. Check that FireFox (FF) is loading the minified version of CKEditor (cke)
2. Check that cache is being used - this helps with loadtimes greatly except for the first request
3. Benchmark cke performance for FF and Chrome using a barebones test to rule out your customizations and configuration. 
   This can help tons if you have a lot of custom code around cke like I do. I take a copy of my site, strip away my code, config, plugins, DOM elements etc until I find what is making the page load slowly. Or the other way around, start with nothing but a page with an editor and profile that against your site.
4. Disable all features and plugins you don't need
5. Make sure you use the latest version of cke and FF
6. Make sure you don't get any errors or bad looking warnings in the console
7. Check with a few different versions of FF and cke

Comment: Oh yeah, for timing JavaScript in FireFox & Chrome, I recommend [`console.time()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.time). It's awesome.